# How to use prysm add validator for private network

Tags: eth-2.0, prysm

I'm current running my own private geth network, and running a beacon-chain(by prysm), How can i use prysm to add validator for my network?

Answer (score 1):

To add a validator to your own private Ethereum network using the Prysm client, you will need ETH to stake, a running beacon node connected to your private network, and the validator client software to manage your validator.
Make sure that your beacon node is configured to point to the deposit contract on your private Geth network. This contract address is needed for the validator to register. In Prysm, this would typically be set in the beacon node configuration with a flag like `--deposit-contract` followed by the address.
Next, you'll need to send the required amount of ETH to your validator's deposit address on your private Geth network. This step is network-specific and would be similar to funding any other account on your private Ethereum network.
If you haven't already, generate your validator keys. Prysm provides a command to do this:

```shell
prysm.sh validator accounts create --keystore-path=/path/to/validator/keys --passwords-dir=/path/to/passwords
```

After funding your validator account, you have to submit the deposit to the deposit contract. This step indicates that your validator is ready to be activated. This deposit can be made using the Prysm `validator` client.
In an actual Ethereum setup, this would be done using the Ethereum Launchpad. However, in your case, for a private network, you might need to manually interact with the deposit contract using a script, because the Launchpad is not designed for private network use. This interaction would be a transaction that invokes the `deposit` function in the deposit contract.
With the deposit submitted, you can now run your validator client. Make sure it is configured to connect to your private beacon node:

```shell
prysm.sh validator --beacon-rpc-provider=127.0.0.1:4000 --keystore-path=/path/to/validator/keys --passwords-dir=/path/to/passwords
```

Replace `127.0.0.1:4000` with the actual IP and port of your running Prysm beacon node.

Comment: yes, i deposit 32 ETH to private-chain's contract. when i run `./prysm.sh validator --wallet-dir=~/Eth2Validators/prysm-wallet-v2 --mainnet=false ---beacon-rpc-provider=127.0.0.1:4000`. show **INFO validator: Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node pubKey=0x9790663c6602 status=UNKNOWN_STATUS**. that's correct?

Comment: it appears that you have followed the correct process.

Comment: yes, but validator didn't join the network 2 days. it's normal?

Comment: No, is not , Check all the steps again. Many reasons can cause this problem. You can go step by step with chatgpt, use this website and set it on gpt4 : https://start.chatgot.io/

Comment: I checked steps again. but still find the issue. validator still print **Waiting for deposit to be observed by beacon node pubKey=0x9790663c6602 status=UNKNOWN_STATUS**